# Cache and cookie in Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

I have tried to delete the cache and cookie using shift+ctrl+del keys. The cookie is removed and it doesn't makes any changes in cookies till the browser reopens. I have to close the browser and open it again to complete the deletion of cookies.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any add-ons installed, try temporarily disabling them and seeing if the problem persists:

[image: ## Heading ##]

Comment: This does not really answer the question, and is more of a comment. (If the OP confirms that this works, *then* it might be suitable as an answer with additional details about which add-on was causing the issue.)

Comment: @Dan It displays lot of ad-dons can you specify which may be the reason for this

Comment: I would try disabling them all, then restarting IE, and seeing if the problem can be reproduced. If yes: then it's something else. If no: then keep enabling them one at a time (and restarting IE) until the problem returns and you can identify which one was causing the issue.